# Skip part of loop while thread is sleeping

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have two parts of code that I want to run in a loop. Sometimes I need to make the loop 'sleep', making each iteration skip the second part. The loop should stop sleeping after a set amount of time (for example using a thread with a call to `thread::sleep`). How do I accomplish this?

```
use std::thread;

let mut sleeping = false;
let mut handle = thread::spawn(|| {});

loop {
    part_1();

    if sleeping {
        continue;
    }

    part_2();

    if some_condition {
        sleeping = true;
        handle = thread::spawn(|| thread::sleep_ms(100));
    }
}
```

In this example, if the condition is met, the `part_2` call would be skipped for some amount of iterations. My use case is continuing to run graphical updates in a game, while freezing the game's logic (such as counting down timers).

Comment: I fear that there might be some terminology confusion here. Are you asking how to can skip executing the second half of the loop for some period of time, and after that amount of time has passed you will resume running the second half?

Comment: It seems you should use a condition or channel to signal that sleeping has ended

Comment: @Shepmaster I have updated the question to clarify. `part_2` should not be called while the thread is sleeping (there is a `continue` before it), but all code before the `continue` is being run unconditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the overhead of threads or even the need to **sleep**. Simply track the time that you should delay executing code until:

```
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

fn part_1() {}
fn part_2() {}
fn some_condition() -> bool {
    false
}

fn main() {
    let mut sleep_until = None;
    loop {
        part_1();

        if let Some(until) = sleep_until {
            if until > Instant::now() {
                continue;
            }
        }

        part_2();

        if some_condition() {
            let now = Instant::now();
            let until = now + Duration::from_millis(500);
            sleep_until = Some(until);
        }
    }
}
```

Although I'd probably avoid the use of `continue` here, and instead embed the logic within:

```
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

fn perform_physics_calculation() {}
fn perform_graphics_render() {}

fn main() {
    let mut next_graphics_update = Instant::now();
    let graphics_delay = Duration::from_millis(500);

    loop {
        let now = Instant::now();
        perform_physics_calculation();

        if next_graphics_update <= now {
            perform_graphics_render();
            next_graphics_update = now + graphics_delay;
        }
    }
}
```

Note in one case I use an `Option<Instant>` and in the other I just use an `Instant`; both cases can make sense.

Comment: I think moving `let now = ...` below `perform_physical_calculation()` would be more accurate, especially if such calculation takes noticeable time.

Comment: @AndrewLygin that's certainly possible. On the other hand, it might be desirable to have a stable time base for the entire "frame" so you don't get strange differences between your physics calculations and graphics rendering, for example. Additionally, getting the current time isn't "free", so you may want to avoid getting it too frequently.

Comment: This is much simpler than using `sleep`. However, the `if until < Instant::now()` should be a `>`, as making this change made the code work.

Comment: @pengowen123 good point; I was too lazy to run the infinite loop until it finished to test it out ^_^.

Comment: @Shepmaster, I agree. The choice between these options depends the exact meaning of *'after a set amount of time'*. Though, if such delay is long enough in comparison with the time of one iteration, the difference might be insignificant. Regarding the cost of getting the current time, I just suggested moving it a bit lower, it wouldn't add another call to `Instant::now()`, so all costs are exactly the same.

Comment: @AndrewLygin but if performing the physics calculation needs the current time (and many game loops do use the time like that), then you'd have to get the time twice. It all depends on code we can't see from the example though.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your `sleeping` variable into a reference-counted atomic boolean so that you can reset it on the sleeping thread.

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn part_1() {}
fn part_2() {}
fn some_condition() -> bool { false }

fn main() {
    let sleeping = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
    let mut handle = None;

    loop {
        part_1();

        if sleeping.load(Ordering::Acquire) {
            continue;
        }

        part_2();

        if some_condition() {
            sleeping.store(true, Ordering::Release);
            let sleeping_clone = sleeping.clone();
            handle = Some(thread::spawn(move || {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
                sleeping_clone.store(false, Ordering::Release);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```